# Turning numbers embedded in deeply nested lists into strings

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, simplifying-expressions

This must have a simple answer, but I cannot think of it.  I want to take the numbers in a list such as:

{1,{2,{{3,4},{5,6}},7,8}

into strings.  ToString will turn the whole list into a string.  And mapping cannot be done either, or I fail to see how to use it.  Somehow, trying to replace using:

x_Integer->ToString[x]

doesn’t work (it turns the x into a string).  This must be elementary, but I just can’t think of how to do this.  Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `:>`, not `->`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, this works.  I have a follow up question, which I hesitate to ask as a separate question.  How do I replace each of the individual strings that arise from the operation you just indicated (or the one in the response below) with the concatenation of a string prefix and the stringed number.  It seems my use of StringReplace is defective. If necessary I will edit the question.

Comment: @J.M. I can use what you suggested to do both things at once, but for specific reasons, I want to accomplish the second bit in a separate step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
l = {1, {2, {{3, 4}, {5, 6}}, 7, 8}};
result=IntegerString[l]
```

> {"1",{"2",{{"3","4"},{"5","6"}},"7","8"}}

Per your comment question, either map on result, or just combine into one map (here prefixing with "a" for example):

```
Map["a" <> # &, result, {-1}]
Map["a" <> IntegerString@# &, l, {-1}]
```

Both give:

> {"a1",{"a2",{{"a3","a4"},{"a5","a6"}},"a7","a8"}}

Comment: Thank you, this is almost the ideal answer, but please see the follow up question in the comments to the question itself ... and then I accept this one, although all answers are really good.

Comment: @EGME see update.

Comment: Excellent the second Map is what I was looking for ... it is hinted at by the answer below yours. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

If I understand your two-step string prefix concatenation correctly then this should work

```
s1 = Map[ToString, l, {-1}];

prefix = "EGME ";
Map[prefix <> # &, s1, {-1}]

(* {"EGME 1", {"EGME 2", {{"EGME 3", "EGME 4"}, {"EGME 5", "EGME 6"}}, "EGME 7", "EGME 8"}} *)
```

---

```
Map[ToString, l, {-1}]

(* {"1", {"2", {{"3", "4"}, {"5", "6"}}, "7", "8"}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really good too.  Please see the follow up question in the comments to the question

Answer (score 2):

If your list consisted of a mixture of integers and non-integers, then it might be better to use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace):

```
l = {1, {2, {{3, 4}, {5, 6.1}}, 7, 8}};

Replace[
    l,
    i_Integer :> "a" <> IntegerString[i],
    {-1}
]
```

> {"a1", {"a2", {{"a3", "a4"}, {"a5", 6.1}}, "a7", "a8"}}

Comment: Thank you, this is also very useful ...